# set QVector data with double* without memory copying

Tags: qt, double, qvector

I have an structure **MyVect** and I am looking to convert my structure **MyVect** to an QVector varibale without making a copy of the memory.

I want to use the same memory reserved by the QVector already initialize.

```
typedef struct MyVect
{
  int size;
  double *data;
}vect;
```

something like that

```
QVector<double> v;

MyVect *vect = new MyVect;
double *val = new double(4);
for(int i =0; i <4; i++)
{
  val[i] = i;
}
vect->size = 4;
vect->data = val;

v.data() = vect->data;// <==example not correct
```

thank for your help in advance

Comment: I don't know why do you need to do it, but your code looks more or less ok. The `vect->data` is valid until vector `v` isn't reallocated, though.

Comment: **It stores its items in adjacent memory locations** From https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html But `append()`, `push_back()`, etc. can reallocate it if required.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, I made a mistake I try to do the opposite. Make the conversion of a MyVect to a QVector. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What doesn't work - an explanation**

What you are trying to do is not possible, i.e. `QVector` doesn't provide a `setData` method to pass in a plain C++ double array (double *).

`v.data() = vect->data;` doesn't work as `v.data()` doesn't return a reference to its internal C++ double array (double *).

**A solution**

What may be a solution, is to let QVector allocate the memory and pass it to your `MyVect` structure.

```
QVector<double> v;
v.resize(4); // Let Qt allocate the C++ double array (double*)

// Initialise your MyVect structure based on the QVector.
MyVect *vect = new MyVect;
vect->data = v.data();
vect->size = v.size();

// Fill the vector using your MyVect struct.
for(int i =0; i < vest->size; i++)
{
  vect->data[i] = i;
}
```